# How to pass a dropdown value to <select> element in angular to auto populate data in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to pass the form data received from database to a html page which contains dropdown values.
I want to prepopulate the data from database to the dropdown.

I am having a controller and its select element in its html page.

**HTML :**

```
                  <div ng-repeat="field in rowFields track by $index">
                                        
                                                    <vc-text labelaccessor="{{field.fieldId}}"
                                                        ng-if="field.fieldType=='TextField' || field.fieldType=='Email'"
                                                        data-model="formdata[field.model]" data-field="field" data-processfield=""
                                                        data-inputtype="field.fieldType" vc-tabkeychange="" vc-blur=""
                                                        maxlength="{{field.maxLen}}" minlength="{{field.maxLen}}"
                                                        allowedchars="{{field.valid_chars}}" vc-focus=""
                                                        ng-keyup=""
                                                        style="font-weight:900">
                                                    </vc-text>          

                                                    
                                                   <vc-select ng-if="field.fieldType=='DropDown'" label="{{field.fieldName}}" whr=''
                                                        tbl='{{field.metaInfo.Table}}' dbval='{{field.metaInfo.Val}}'

                                                        
                                                        dblbl='{{field.metaInfo.DisplayLabel}}' data-accessor="formdata[field.model]"
                                                        labelaccessor="{{field.model}}" data-datalist="field.metaInfo.datalist"
                                                        labeldatalist="{{field.metaInfo.datalist}}" sql="{{field.metaInfo.sql}}"
                                                        data-field="field" 
                                                        vc-change="businessValidations(formdata[field.model],[field.model])"
                                                        vc-blur="okBlur([field.model],field.fieldId,field.fieldName,field.metaInfo)" 
                                                        style="font-weight:900" vc-focus="onFocus(field)"
                                                        >
                                                        
                                                    </vc-select>

                      </div>
```

**Controller :**

```
$scope.getApplication = function()
{
    $scope.formdata = {};
    $scope.formdata.status = {};
    $scope.bdeApp = getAppAllocatedApp.get({
        'processId':$routeParams.processId
    });
    $scope.bdeApp.$promise.then(function (response) { 
        if(response.result.length === 0)
        { 
            toastr.error("No record found..!!")
        }
        else{ 

          
            $scope.formdata = response.result;
            $scope.formdata['pl_banking'] = "Other Bank"
            $rootScope.DEStartTimeValue = $scope.formdata.DEStartDate;
            $scope.getAppStatus = false;
            $scope.SubmitBtnStatus = true;
            $scope.startTimer();

        }
```

Here I am calling getApplication to recieve data in '**response.result**' which i am passing to formdata which is using to render the element in HTML page.

Here for text field i am easily able to populate the data, but for dropdown i am not able to populate the data.

Content for vc-select :

```html
<div class="col-md-6 customline">
  <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">{{field.fieldName}}</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          <select 
            ng-required="(field.validations.indexOf('Blank') === -1)?false:true" 
            ng-model="accessor.selectedItem" 
            ng-change="ddlChange()"  
            ng-blur="ddlBlur(this)"  
            tabindex="{{field.fieldOrder}}"
            focus
            id="{{id}}"
            name= "{{field.fieldName}}"
            ng-disabled="((processfield | filter: {fieldId:field.fieldId})[0].enable==0) || disabled || (field.isRej == 1 && section != 0)"
            class="{{bg}} form-control col-sm-4"
            style="width: 225px"
            ng-options="item as item.displaylabel for item in datalist"
            ng-selected = "{formdata[field.model]}"
            ng-focus="onFocus(field,prevfield)"
          >
          <option></option>
          </select>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. I have tried to resolve this but does not get any result.

Comment: why did you tag this with codeigniter?

Comment: This project is based on codeigniter framework.

Comment: ok fine. It's just that the question is not at all related to codeigniter, so the tag shouldn't be used as it doesn't matter to the question in the first place.